# remove all insignificant whitespace from tex source

Tags: sourcecode

Is there an existing tool for removing all insignificant whitespace from the source of a tex document? I'd like to run this before calling [latexindent](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) to see if I can have an autoformatter tool that converts tex source to some canonical style.

So far my approach is to convert all consecutive whitespace to a single space, except for when there are two consecutive newlines (which may signal a paragraph), and when there is a `%` comment, which comments until the next newline. [Here is the script I am using.](https://gist.github.com/goretkin/4d0576b63c813e96d033a485d5970946)

It doesn't handle a handful of cases. For example, it keeps the following newlines

```
\usepackage{a}

\usepackage{b}
```

Comment: Insignificant whitespace? For TeX's processing `\usepackage{a}\usepackage{b}` seems fine, but does an author want to use that style? What is insignificant to you somebody else might think of a "structrual element". So what do you actually refer to?

Comment: Does it correctly handle `\obeylines`, `\obeyspaces`, `verbatim`, `alltt`, etc? In general, this isn't as simple as it might appear! Since all of those commands are built from *standard* TeX features, there is nothing to stop the user devising new macros with similar behaviour  within the TeX source being compiled. Of course a tool that doesn't handle any of that may still be useful, but if you make it public you need to document its limitations!

Comment: `\verb|    |` and similar commands make it impossible to do this in general.

Comment: @alephzero those are some of the "handful" of cases I had in mind. (Well, really I only had \verbatim in mind.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I am convinced that it is impossible to do it in general. But it would still be great to get close.

Comment: 'latexindent' removes leading and trailing white space. It can also modify line breaks and remove some blank lines. If you can post a clear example of what you have, and what you'd like it to look like, that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful if the input is arbitrary tex code, here for example are three lines with a double space, followed in each case by the same, but with a single space. the output is different in each case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily

1 x\verb|  |x

1 x\verb| |x

2 {\obeyspaces a  b}

2 {\obeyspaces a b}

3 a^^  a

3 a^^ a

\end{document}
```

Comment: So it may be that it is impossible to achieve the task of removing insignificant white space purely syntactically. The problem might be as complicated as parsing and understanding tex code to begin with. I wish there were a way to do this, still. So if you have any leads, please let me know.

Comment: @Gus I'm not sure what you want, the vast majority of documents (apart from tex tutorials) don't use verbatim, and the vast majority of those could have spaces normalized with a simple `s/ +/ /g` replace in sed or perl or python or whatever.  But it will break some documents and basically why bother? I doubt you will find any off-the-shelf solution as documenting the cases when it doesn't work is tricky and there is very little call for such a normalisation.